# Javascript 'require()' method

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

In python, when you import a module the statements inside the 
'if name == *main*' block of the imported module is not executed.

Is there any equivalent approach which can prevents the execution of unwanted statements in the imported module in javascript?

Comment: [Accessing the main module#](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_accessing_the_main_module), you mean this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Via [fuyushimoya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1737627/fuyushimoya)'s comment.

> When a file is run directly from Node, require.main is set to its
>   module. That means that you can determine whether a file has been run
>   directly by testing
>
> ```
> require.main === module
> ```
>
> For a file foo.js, this will be true if run via node foo.js, but false
>   if run by require('./foo').

— [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_accessing_the_main_module)

So:

```
if (require.main === module) {
    // Code that runs only if the module is executed directly
} else {
    // Code that runs only if the code is loaded as a module
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure his condition though, as I'm still learning python, if in python this way is to create a master-slave structure, then maybe [cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) with `cluster.isMaster` is what he wants?

Comment: @fuyushimoya .. in python it is .. 
`if __name__ == '__main__':
     //code`
thank you :)

Comment: In addition to this answer, common pattern to include some statements in module which will not be executed when module is required is: `if (!module.parent) { // not executed with require } else { // executed only with require }`

Answer (score -2):

Simply group your statements inside functions, and export the functions you want.

```
exports.function1 = new function () {
  //some code
}
function function2() {
  //some other code 
}
```

More on it [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html).

Comment: You seem to have completely misunderstood the question.